# Não consigo pegar valor da JTable

Tags: java, table, tabela-html

Entao, eu estava tentando procurar valores em um JTable, testando se oque esta na linha x e coluna y bate com um objeto, mas não vai de jeito nenhum e não sei porque. Ja tentei de tudo =(

```
public Integer[] getRowIndex(Object value, int column) {
    ArrayList<Integer> rows = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = model.getRowCount(); i > 0; i--) {
        if (table.getValueAt(i--, column).equals(value)) {
            System.out.println("eai coldizera 2");
            rows.add(i--);
        }
    }
    return rows.toArray(new Integer[rows.size()]);
}
```

Resolvi =D

```
public Integer[] getRowIndex(Object value, int column) {
    ArrayList<Integer> rows = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
        if (table.getValueAt(i, column).equals(value)) {
            rows.add(i);
        }
    }
    return rows.toArray(new Integer[rows.size()]);
}
```

Comment: Sua pergunta ja foi respondida nas duas que linkei, da uma lida com calma nas respostas.

Comment: Consegui resolver =D